# Finding inflection points of 2D BSplineFunction

Tags: equation-solving, splines, differential-geometry

This code creates a jagged line in two dimensions and fits a BSpline function to it.

```
pointSources = {{10, 10}, {30, 80}, {50, 50}, {90, 90}, {70, 55}};
stepSize = 5;
noise = 1; pointDistances = 
 N[Table[EuclideanDistance[pointSources[[i]], 
    pointSources[[i + 1]]], {i, 1, Length[pointSources] - 1}]];
segments = Round[pointDistances/stepSize];
directPoints = N[Table[
    step = (pointSources[[i + 1]] - pointSources[[i]])/segments[[i]];
    Table[
     pointSources[[i]] + step*j + 
      RandomInteger[{-noise, noise}, 2], {j, 1, 
      segments[[i]] - 1}], {i, 1, Length[segments]}]];
path = Prepend[
   Flatten[MapThread[
     Append[#1, #2] &, {directPoints, Rest[pointSources]}], 1], 
   pointSources[[1]]];
g = Evaluate[BSplineFunction[path, SplineDegree -> 1000]]
Show[Graphics[{Black, PointSize[0.02], Point[pointSources],Black, Line[path]}], ParametricPlot[{g[t]}, {t, 0, 1}]]
```

So far so good. g is a function with one parameter that ranges from 0 to 1. What I want to do is find the zero-curvature, inflection points of the fitted curve, of which there are two obvious ones. It seems like it should be straightforward but my playing around with second derivatives (g'') hasn't been fruitful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the inflection points as follows.

Here is the differential geometric part:

```
(*unit tangent*)
τ = t \[Function] Evaluate[g'[t]/Sqrt[g'[t].g'[t]]];
(*curvature vector*)
κ = t \[Function] Evaluate[τ'[t]/Sqrt[g'[t].g'[t]]];
(*absolute curvature function*)
f = t \[Function] Evaluate[κ[t].RotationMatrix[Pi/2].τ[t]];
```

And here a two-step method to find the roots of the absolute curvature function:

```
(*plotting with MeshFunctions -> {(#2&)} to obtain approximations
to the roots of f*)
plot = Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}, MeshFunctions -> {(#2 &)}, 
   Mesh -> {{0.}}, MeshStyle -> Red];
gc = Cases[plot, _GraphicsComplex, ∞][[1]];
tvalsapprox = gc[[1]][[Cases[plot, _Point, ∞][[1, 1]], 1]];
(*using the approximate roots as starting values for FindRoot*)
tvals = t /. FindRoot[f[t], {t, #}] & /@ tvalsapprox
```

[image]

> {0.448325, 0.892943, 0.147268, 0.935865, 0.0324412, 0.704332, 0.194042}

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Henrik for the curvature code. And that's a neat trick to 'prime' the FindRoot function. Though wouldn't something like this work also?

```
tvalsapprox = 
 Flatten[Position[
    Table[If[f[t]*f[t + 0.01] < 0, 1, 0], {t, 0, 0.99,
       0.01}], 1]]/100.
tvals = t /. FindRoot[f[t], {t, #}] & /@ tvalsapprox
```

Comment: Of course. That's basically what `MeshFunctions` do... =)